# Matlab while loop issues bisection

Tags: matlab

I am new to MATLAB and have encountered a problem on an assignment. The assignment is to use the bisection method. My original code was:

```
a = -0.5;
b = 1.1;
f=@(x) x^5-2*x^4+3*x^3-2*x^2+x-1-cos(30*x);
val1 = f(a);
val2 = f(b);
p1a1 = val1*val2;
save('A1.dat','p1a1','-ascii')

%bisection

for i = 0:100
    c = (a+b)/2;
    if f(c) >= -0.000000001 && f(c) <= 0.000000001
        answer = c;
    elseif f(c) > 0
        b = c;
    else a = c;
    end
end
answer = c;
save('A2.dat','answer','-ascii')
```

However, I needed to count the number of iterations it took, so I changed the second part of the code (after "bisection") to:

```
tolerance = 0.000000001;
count = 0;
c =(a+b)/2;
while abs(f(c))>tolerance
    count=count+1;
    if f(c) > 0
        b = c;
    else
        a = c;
    end
end
answer = c;
```

Where c would show the zero of the function, within the prescribed tolerance. The new code won't run however, and I cannot seem to figure out where i have gone wrong. Apologies if it is something simple

Comment: to avoid potential infinite loop, stopping criterion must be |b-a|<eps. Reason: for numerically inaccurate f(.) function, function without zero or for very small eps you are not sure that |f(c)|<eps is ever fulfilled. On the other side |b-a|<eps will happen for sure.

Comment: @PicaudVincent Note that `<=` would probably be better than `<`, given that (by definition) `eps` is the smallest representable value. Also `eps = 2.2e-16` on my machine, the tolerance used in the question should be of no concern for numerical accuracy.

Comment: @Wolfie yes sure you are right

Answer (score 1):

You're not updating the value of `c` inside the loop, it never changes which means you're stuck in the `while` loop. Copy the `c = (a+b)/2` definition to inside the loop, as you had it before.

```
c = (a+b)/2;
while abs(f(c))>tolerance
    count=count+1;        
    if f(c) > 0
        b = c;
    else
        a = c;
    end
    c = (a+b)/2; % <<<<<< This is needed to avoid an infinite loop!
end
answer = c;
```

The bisection method is guaranteed to converge to a root (if it exists), but you should be careful with `while` loops for numerical methods. In particular, add a maximum iteration counter

```
maxIters = 1000;
c = (a+b)/2;
while abs(f(c)) > tolerance && count < maxIters
    % Code as before ...
end
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much. I tried to put c in the while loop, but I put it at the top, before the "count=count+1. Now it makes sense. Also, thank you for the helpful tip about setting the max number of iterations. This will undoubtedly help with future coding!

Comment: @Pat No problem, consider marking this answer as accepted (the green tick mark under the voting buttons) if it answers your question!